# How to use version in perl?

Tags: perl

I am using windows platform and padre editor for running the perl program

```
use 5.11.0;
$data = 1232;
print $data;
```

Resulting the error is

```
Global symbol "$data" requires explicit package name at file.pl line 2.
Global symbol "$data" requires explicit package name at file.pl line 3.
```

Comment: I believe `use 5.10` and up will enable warnings and strict mode by default. Thus the error which can be corrected by using the `my` keyword.

Comment: 5.10 doesn't, but 5.11 and above imply `use strict` when you `use _version_`.

Comment: @JimDavis Thanks for the correction. I knew it was one of the newer versions. :)

Comment: @squiguy Thanks for chiming in with the _reason_ why declaring is needed.   I updated my answer with your good info.

Comment: of course, if you've followed the standard advice - ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings;` this would be a moot point.

Comment: 5.11 is a dev (test) version. It's doesn't really make sense to have/require 5.11.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your version statement.

The problem is that you have not declared the variable `$data` ... and (as mentioned in squiguy's comment) versions of Perl starting with 5.11.0 and up [automatically `use strict` when you `use __version__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5110delta.html#Implicit-strictures).  `use strict` means that you need to declare all variables before using them.

This works:

```
use 5.11.0;
my $data = 1232;
print $data;
```

This is more explicit, maybe more "understandable":

```
use 5.11.0;
my $data;     # declare the local variable we are about to use 
$data = 1232; # set initial value 
print $data;  # see if it got the value
```